# How to design declarative streams with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, observable

### My Problem

I want to learn more about writing declarative/functional code with RxJS. I'm trying to use splitting, merging, and other forms of stream coordination to encapsulate the logic, rather than imperatively handling things. I have an example scenario that hopefully you can help me with.

### Context

When a user clicks, I want to log statistics about their click & hover behavior. I also want to show a notification if the statistics are considered 'primary'.

```js
const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');

// emits very frequently, as the user moves the mouse around the screen
const hover$ = new Subject<CustomHoverEvent>();

// The user can hover their mouse around the application, and when
// they click, emit the latest hover event. If there was a click without
// any hovers, dont emit anything.
const lastHoverEvent$ = hover$.pipe(
    buffer(click$),
    map(events => events[events.length - 1]),
    filter(event => !!event)
);

const [primaryHover$, secondaryHover$] = partition(
    lastHoverEvent$,
    (event) => event.isPrimaryHover()
);

const primaryHoverStats$ = primaryHover$.pipe(
    map(event => calculatePrimaryHoverStats(event)
);

const primaryHoverStatsNotification$ = primaryHoverStats$.pipe(
    map(stats => createNotification(stats)
);

const secondaryHoverStats$ = secondaryHover$.pipe(
    map(event => calculateSecondaryHoverStats(event)
);

const hoverStats$ = merge(primaryHoverStats$, secondaryHoverStats$);


hoverStats$.subscribe(stats => logStats(stats));

primaryHoverStatsNotification$.subscribe(notification => notify(notification));
```

Here is how the above streams currently work. Each color represents the code that is run due to each subscription. All of the upstream work is repeated for each subscriber (buffering the events, and calculating the stats for primary).

[image]

But here is how I actually want it to work. Where the work that is done along the pipeline is not repeated, and each subscriber only handles its part.

[image]

To fix this, I added  few `share()` operators, in order to multicast the work that has already been done.

```js
const lastHoverEvent$ = hover$.pipe(
    buffer(click$),
    map(events => events[events.length - 1]),
    filter(event => !!event),
    share()
);

...

const primaryHoverStats$ = primaryHover$.pipe(
    map(event => calculatePrimaryHoverStats(event),
    share()
);
```

The type of flow I am trying to replicate looks like this with plain functions.

```js
const lastHoverEvent = getLastHoverEvent();
let hoverStats;
if (lastHoverEvent.isPrimaryHover()) {
    hoverStats = calculatePrimaryHoverStats(lastHoverEvent);
    const notification = createNotification(hoverStats);
    notify(notification);
} else {
    hoverStats = calculateSecondaryHoverStats(lastHoverEvent);
}
logStats(hoverStats);
```

or like this with a `map` in the original code

```js
hover$.pipe(
    buffer(click$),
    map(events => events[events.length - 1]),
    filter(event => !!event),
    map(event => {
        let hoverStats;
        if (event.isPrimaryHover()) {
            hoverStats = calculatePrimaryHoverStats(event);
            const notification = createNotification(hoverStats);
            notify(notification);
        } else {
            hoverStats = calculateSecondaryHoverStats(event);
        }
        return hoverStats;
    })
).subscribe(stats => logStats(stats));
```

### Questions

1. Is adding `share` to your streams really necessary to allow RxJS to work this way? In the 'plain functions' example above, it seems very simple and nothing out of the ordinary, but when you try to do it by splitting up the streams into separate events, duplicate upstream work is done which seems a bit unintuitive to me.

   I feel like I'm missing something. Is this not a good way to go about writing RxJS? I feels so right, when thinking about the logic in terms of the diagrams above, like interconnected streams... but the overhead of `share` seems weird. Should I just stick to something like the `map` solution in the last code example?

2. (unrelated question) I used `buffer` to get the latest hover event on click. I was thinking about using `ReplaySubject` and `withLatestFrom()`, to reduce the in-memory storage of hover events (because I only need the latest one).

   ```js
   const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
   const hover$ = new ReplaySubject<CustomHoverEvent>(1);
   const lastHoverEvent$ = click$.pipe(
       withLatestFrom(hover$),
       map(([click, hover]) => hover),
       ...
   );
   ```

   but this doesn't work because I need the `click$` event to clear whatever hover events have already passed. For example, if a user clicks 2 times in a row without hovering on anything, I don't want a stale/old hover event to be retrieved.

   Is there a better way to do this without `buffer`? It seems wasteful to store all the events in memory just to get the last one. I was hoping to find a size configuration on `buffer`, and set it to 1, but I don't see any.

Comment: Are the 2 diagrams the same or is it just my eyes?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Based on my understanding, the first one highlights that new (and redundant) subscribers will be added every time to the main source. Although that is expected, this is not the behavior the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to question 1

Although it may seem a bit counterintuitive at first, `share()` is definitely needed in order to not unnecessarily subscribe to sources.

Basically, every observable source can be reduced so something like this:

```
new Observable(subscriber => {
  ...
});
```

*Note: in case of Subjects, things are slightly different*.

For example, here are some relevant parts of [`fromEvent`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/fromEvent.ts#L260):

```
return new Observable<T>((subscriber) => {
  const handler = (...args: any[]) => subscriber.next(1 < args.length ? args : args[0]);

  // ...
}
```

Despite defining data sources very declaratively(e.g. `hover$` -> `lastHoverEvent$` -> `primaryHover$` -> ...), every subscription will result in subscribing to the source once again. In case of `hover$`, each subscription to any of its **derived sources**(e.g. `primaryHover$`) will result in a **new subscriber** being added to the `hover$` Subject's subscribers list.

The way the `share()` operator prevents subscribing multiple times to a data source is by employing a [**local Subject**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L181) that will keep track of all subscribers. The original data source will be [subscribed only once](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L203-L230), by checking how many subscribers are active.

### Answer to question 2

I think you can still go with the `withLatestFrom` approach, but using a `Subject` instead of a `ReplaySubject`.

```
const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const hover$ = new Subject<CustomHoverEvent>();
const lastHoverEvent$ = click$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(hover$),

  // Covering the case where `hover$` has been cleared.
  filter(([, hover]) => !!hover),
  
  map(([click, hover]) => hover),
  tap({ next: () => {
    // Clearing the possible stale hover events.
    hover$.next(null);
  }}),
);
```

Here are the scenarios I can think of based on the above snippet:

1. the user hovers first so `hover$` will `next()` the latests hover event; when the user clicks, due to using [`withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L83), only the latest value will be used
2. if user clicks 2 times: after the first click, `hover$.next(null)` will be invoked and so the value that `withLatestFrom` keeps with regards to `hover$` will be `null`; then, when the user clicks the second time, the `filter` condition will not pass; however, if the user hovers again, the internal value of `hover$` will be updated accordingly and so, if the user clicks, the `filter` pass will check

Comment: clever solution for #2 :) I tend to find `tap` smelly, but this might be fair game. for #1, do you have any habits or practices you follow when breaking up larger observables into chunks? I have a discussion here as well, would like to get more thoughts https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/discussions/7327

Comment: @JamesLemieux IMO the best advice I could give is to explore and understand the source code. That's the approach I took with RxJS. I make sure that, before following 'best practices', I understand what's going on under the hood. Concretely, in this situation, I knew what the problem was(i.e. Observable's callback being invoked every time) and I was aware of what `share()` does behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the advice, I'll make sure to read the source code. I know `share()` uses a Subject, just wasn't sure if people generally use it a lot to split up their code/streams. or if there is a different paradigm when it comes to breaking up streams